# Configure mongo for one shot full db read

Tags: mongodb, read-only-database

I have a kubernetes cluster on bare metal with 3 machines having 8Gb of ram each. All my apps and a mongodb 4.0.9 replicaset runs on it.
There is an import program that:

1. Download a 8Gb mongo dump from external source and restore it in fresly created database A. There is one collection whitout indexes.
2. Fully browse the restored collection with one find({}) and 1M next().
3. Emit amqp messages for each doc, then messages are stored in mongo database B, C, D.
4. Drop the database A.

Part 2 use a lot of ram.

How should I configure mongo database A (and let database B normal) to reduce at max the footprint of the import operation? (Because more important tasks are running in the cluster)

For example, can I configure mongo to not create cache for the temporary collection?

Comment: Welcome to the site, what is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: Are you trying the mongorestore operation consumes more RAM ?

Comment: With the current description it sounds like you have a program running on a local machine that connects to a remote 3-member replica set. If that isn't correct, can you clarify how your program relates to MongoDB? For example, are you downloading a backup from a replica set and restoring to a local `mongod` instance? Also, are you doing any operations on the data (such as aggregation) when you browse the collection or just fetching all documents? Lastly, what is your goal as far as restoring, reading, and then dropping the collection. Is that to verify a backup?

Comment: Thanks for your interest Stennie. I have added precisions.

Comment: You can't limit the memory usage for a specific collection within a deployment, but if you want to minimise the impact of this temporary ingestion I would consider standing up a standalone `mongod` with a smaller [`cacheSizeGB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) value. Once the import is done, you could shutdown that `mongod`. This will also avoid unnecessary replication overhead since you are planning on dropping collection `A` anyway. Another option would to have your app read the BSON dump directly.

Comment: Thanks you Stennie I will try cacheSizeGB on another standalone instance. Sorry i can't even vote for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Starting in MongoDB 3.4, the default WiredTiger internal cache size is the larger of either:

- 50% of (RAM - 1 GB),
- or 256 MB.

For example, In your case from the 8GB of RAM the WiredTiger cache will use 3.5GB of RAM (0.5 * (8 GB - 1 GB) = 3.5 GB).

This can be reduced to for example to 1GB by using the following admin command only when the `mongorestore` operation happens.

```
db.adminCommand( { "setParameter": 1, "wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig": "cache_size=1G"})
```

and revert this back to 3.5 GB once the restoration is completed.

**Note:**

*By reducing the wired tiger cache size will increase the time to restore the data.*

Comment: Thanks you many, but I don't wan't to change all the replica set since others database are'in it. I just want the temporary collection fetchto be quiet and take not a lot of ressources.

Comment: Resizing the WiredTiger cache at runtime may have signficant performance impacts, particularly with a replica set deployment. I would not recommend this as a general optimisation strategy for a production environment: it would be better to set [engineConfig.cacheSizeDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) as a configuration option on startup.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie for your inputs. This helped me with how to approach a problem differently.